# Error handler: Not blocking error

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

The problem is that the error handler gets over ruled and I am still getting the error after the loop runs correctly for 1 time. Please help me out.

The error comes at row: "ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Final").Range("B2").Offset(j, i).Value = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName(HTML_Class)(m).getElementsByTagName("td")(i).innerText"
But, it gives error in the 2nd iteration, after running it correctly once that is it gives error on the 3rd page of the site I need to scrape.

I dont understand what is happening. Please help me out, if possible.

```
Sub Web_Scraping()

  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Final").Range("A1:Z10000").ClearContents

  Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

  objIE.Top = 0
  objIE.Left = 0
  objIE.Width = 800
  objIE.Height = 600

  objIE.Visible = False

  HTML_Class = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("C6").Value
  i = 0
  j = 0
  k = -1

Next_Page:
  Err.Clear
  k = k + 1
  Do
    m = 0
    On Error GoTo Error
    'Site masked below for privacy
    Site = "xyz.com"
    objIE.Navigate (Site)

    Do
      DoEvents
    Loop Until objIE.readystate = 4    

    'objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("div")
    Do
      On Error GoTo Next_Page

      For i = 0 To 6
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Final").Range("B2").Offset(j, i).Value = _
          objIE.document.getElementsByClassName(HTML_Class)(m).getElementsByTagName("td")(i).innerText
      Next i
      m = m + 1
      j = j + 1
    Loop Until (Err.Number <> 0)

  Loop Until (Err.Number <> 0)
Error:
  Err.Clear
  MsgBox "Done!"

  objIE.Quit
  Set objIE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm unclear on how `Loop Until (Err.Number <> 0)` can ever be true if `Err.Clear` is right after `Next_Page:` and you fall back into `On Error GoTo Next_Page`.

Comment: My thinking was that it will clear the error value and run things from top again. if there is an error in `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Final").Range("B2").Offset(j, i).Value = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName(HTML_Class)(m).getElementsByTagName("td")(i).innerText` it should go to `Next_Page`, which it does for the first time but throws me an error the second time. (Note: I tried this with and without `Err.Clear`

Comment: What's the error (message)? And I agree with @Jeeped - your logic is... odd. What kinds of errors do you expect? Usually, it's better to program "around" errors you know can occur so that they don't occur. Error handling is for what you don't expect.

Comment: Also, it's very difficult, if not impossible, to give good advice if you don't give us code we can *test*. It's understandable that you may not want to provide a private website. But couldn't you reproduce the problem on some public site and provide steps to reproduce it for those who want to help?

Comment: Do <a bunch of stuff> until you hit an error. But if you hit an error, don't evaluate it in the Do ... Loop Until. Go back several steps, clear the error and start all over. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: thanks for the responses guys! I will try and replicate the code for some dummy site and share with you the exact code if I still get the error. Thanks,